# MAUI Entry Control Font Size issue on Android

Tags: android, fonts, maui

Newbie to MAUI cross-platform programming.  Pretty much using the controls out of the box on VS2022 version 17.9.0 and IOS 17.x and Android API 33/34.
Between the IOS and Android emulators, the font looks normal in an entry control on IOS but gets really tiny on Android.  Labels work fine.
I tried setting FontSize, but that only worked in IOS.
My markup is really basic at this point.

I'm sure the answer is something really basic, but I can't seem to find it.

[shows the difference the same code looks like on android/iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1qvN.png)

No special configurations, nuget packages, or settings.

Comment: Can you please post the corresponding XAML Code for your screenshot? Looking at your screenshot, it could be, that the outer layout container (e.g. grid) is causing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andre Kraemer's comment was the clue I needed.  I was using a grid container and that was causing the font issue.  When I put similar markup in a FlexLayout, it rendered properly on an android emulator (and android device).

Answer (score 0):

The `OnPlatform` class can be used in XAML to set font properties per platform. The example below sets different font sizes on different platforms:

```
<Entry
    FontSize="{OnPlatform iOS=30, Android=40, WinUI=20}"
    Text="this is maui project"/>
```

For more details about font setting, you can refer to [Fonts in .NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/fonts?view=net-maui-8.0)

Comment: I did try the OnPlatform markup you suggested, but it didn't solve my problem.  Good info, though!